# Tap a cell in a section in UITableview in automation for an iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, instruments

I am building an iPhone app which has a table consisting of many sections. The sections have their corresponding cells. I am writing a script for uiautomation using instruments. How can i automate tapping to a particular cell in a particular section.